# Mysql insert unknown column error. 0x is unknown column in this query

Tags: mysql

I am getting this Unknown column '0x' in 'field list' error. I do not know what should I do to remove this error. please help me

```
INSERT INTO `wp_wpgmza` 
        (`id`, `map_id`, `address`, `description`, `pic`, 
        `link`, `icon`, `lat`, `lng`, `anim`, `title`, 
        `infoopen`, `category`, `approved`, `retina`, `type`, 
        `did`, `sticky`, `other_data`, `latlng`, `lnglat`) 
VALUES(4, 1, 'Dickerldorf 7, 4600, Wels, Austria', '', '', 
        '', '', '48.17400025', '14.063978731278869', '0', 
        '<strong>Huemer, Jozef</strong>', '0', '', 1, 0, 
        0, '', 0, 'a:0:{}', 
        0x000000000101000000779fe3a3451648403cf7fcd1c1202c40, 
        '0x'),
```

should I remove the 0x from the values?

Comment: have you tried wrapping 0x000000000101000000779fe3a3451648403cf7fcd1c1202c40 in single quotes too?

Comment: yes but still getting same error.

Comment: This is a issue of WP Google Maps extension, please write to they support: https://www.wpgmaps.com/support/